# Overlapping fields in PagedView

Tags: android, android-layout

I use Greendroid in my app and use the PagedView from that library.

My PaddedLayout:

```
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:greendroid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.cyrilmottier.android.gdcatalog">

    <greendroid.widget.PagedView
        android:id="@+id/paged_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:gravity="bottom"
            >

                      <Button
        android:id="@+id/mal_up"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Flirt"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="12pt"
        android:typeface="serif" />

        <greendroid.widget.PageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/page_indicator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />  
        </LinearLayout>

</merge>
```

My Entity Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mal_iv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"/>

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
          android:text="@string/username" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mal_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#FF3100" 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:text="@string/age" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mal_age"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#FF3100"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"  />
      <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/gender" />    
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mal_gender"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#FF3100"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


</LinearLayout>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Problem:

The PaddedLayout and my Entity Layout overlaps, please help

Answer (score 0):

You can put the TextFields and the Button into a

```
<LinearLayout ... android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout>
```

And this into a HorizontalScrollView.

If you do this. The user is able to scroll down to the button on smaller devices.

As far as i can see there is to less screenspace for a different solution.

So the code could look like this. (The flirt button is within the linearlayout which is within the scrollview)

Your entity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mal_iv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"/>

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
          android:text="@string/username" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mal_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#FF3100" 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:text="@string/age" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mal_age"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#FF3100"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"  />
      <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/gender" />    
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mal_gender"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#FF3100"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/mal_up"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Flirt"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="12pt"
        android:typeface="serif" />

</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: i don't want to use a scroll view. the imageview should scale automatically